# joda time to sql MS access database

Tags: java, sql, jodatime

How to insert date in sql table from java query and get date when called from the program using joda time API. because I am using joda time API for doing calculations with the recieved date?

Comment: ... What are you using to talk to the database?  Straight up JDBC?  An ORM?  I know hibernate has/had an extension to use JodaTime; otherwise, you could use the [@PostLoad annotation](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PostLoad) to translate it from whatever type to an entity object.  For JDBC, translate it after the retrieve.

Comment: JDBC driver and I use statements like INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (DATE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JDBC, just translate from the JodaTime date to a JDK date before the persist.
Something along these lines:

```
public void insertDateValue(DateTime value) throws SQLException {

    String insertString = "INSERT INTO tableName(datecolumn) VALUES(?)";

    PreparedStatement insert = null;

    try {
        insert = connection.prepareStatement(insertString);

        // Important part is right here:
        insert.setDate(1, new Date(value.getMillis()));
        // Oh, and the new object should be java.sql.Date


        insert.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                // Should maybe do something here
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (insert != null) {
            insert.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The reverse can be done when retrieving from the database.